# OOP based tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want button 1 on to the second frame

[image]

```
from tkinter import *

root =Tk()

class Graphic():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.colour = "blue"

        self.frame_input = Frame(master, height =100, width=100, bg="green").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label_process = Label(master, width=30).grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.frame_button = Frame(master,height=100,width=100, bg="red").grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.button = Button(master, text="1", bg=self.colour).grid(row=0, column=0)


if '__main__'  == __name__:

    grafic = Graphic(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is the point to create frames and never use them? Do you want `frame_button` as master to your Button?

Comment: I rolled back your question to show the original code; updating the question to ask a brand new question in response to answers invalidates the answers (I did edit the answer to address both problems).

Answer (score 2):

The first argument for each widget is the parent to attach to. You told it to attach to `master`, and it did. If you want it attached to the second frame, change:

```
self.button = Button(master, text="1", bg=self.colour).grid(row=0, column=0)
```

to:

```
self.button = Button(self.frame_button, text="1", bg=self.colour)
self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Note, this still doesn't work, because you tried to chain your `grid` calls, and `grid` returns `None`, so all your attributes (including `self.frame_button`) are `None`, not widgets. To fix, split the creation and layout steps for *all* your widgets:

```
self.frame_input = Frame(master, height =100, width=100, bg="green")
self.frame_input.grid(row=0, column=0)

self.label_process = Label(master, width=30)
self.label_process.grid(row=1, column=0)

self.frame_button = Frame(master,height=100,width=100, bg="red")
self.frame_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

self.button = Button(self.frame_button, text="1", bg=self.colour)
self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: Thank's for Help sir

Comment: @Student: You're welcome. If this answered your question adequately, please click the check box on the left side of the answer (near the voting arrows) to mark it as accepted (it helps others know the problem is fully resolved, and hey, bonus rep for both you and me is a nice side-benefit).